# How to find a list of index using Cypher

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I've created an INDEX using cypher for my `:Person` label, but I cannot find any way of printing out a list of indexes or constraints available to my Neo4j system.

Is this something that is doable via Cypher?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope. There's not even a way to list labels:

https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/issues/1287

There are some [REST calls for this](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/rest-api-schema-indexes.html#rest-api-list-indexes-for-a-label), and the undocumented `schema` command in neo4j-shell is handy.

*Edit: Update for 3.0 with the new stored procedures!*

`CALL db.labels()`

Comment: AFAIK, still no way to list labels from the overall database in cypher.

Comment: In 3.0 you can do `CALL db.labels()`

Comment: @Lazydev thanks! it's always hard to keep answers up to date.

Answer (score 11):

As Eve pointed out, you can get labels by calling CALL.Labels(). To get indexes just do:

```
CALL db.indexes()
```

Also if you do `CALL db.` in your neo4j browser you will see all the functions available.

Answer (score 3):

In browser you can use `:schema` or `schema` in the shell to print out all the indexes and constraints.

Answer (score 2):

(Applicable to neo4j version 2.3.1 or later)

To get indexes via REST use this:

```
curl http://localhost:7474/db/data/schema/index/
```

In the neo4j console you can run the `:schema` command to get all indexes & constraints.

[image: Showing schema in neo4j console]